# How to share using a asp.net page on two asp.net site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, redirect, popup

I have two asp.net website A and B, they are deployed on two different server with different domain, however, they are associated to the same business, they both contains link to direct each other, and they use sessionId to identiy users.

On site A, I have a help page and several help form pages, when user click a link, the help page will be popuped as a embeded page. Currently I want to popup the same help page on site B, however after I tested, I found out some problems.

1. the css are missing on site B, no the page looks weird
2. the js are also missing on site B, so most of help features stop working

I am wonderring if there is a smart way to share Help page on different asp.net site, or any better way to create duplicate pages on site B.

Thanks

Comment: What methods you've used to request pages of different site?

Comment: hi AVD, on site A, I used facebox jquery plus-in to make a popup, on site B I use js functions with css to control let popup div display and other area become obscure